# Carry variable through a SCSS loop

Tags: css, sass

I have the following scss:

```
//############  colour vars
$pageA:#C70F3F;
$pageB:#7f153b;
$pageC:#0c5451;
$pageD:#9f1023;

//############ page type array
$pageTypes: pageA pageB pageC pageD;

//############  loop
@each $pageType in $pageTypes {
  $thisColor:str-insert(#{$pageType}, "$", 1);
  .#{$pageType} {
    background-color:$thisColor;
    background-image:url(../images/background/#{$pageType}.jpg);
  }
}
```

The desired result is:

```
.pageA {
  background-color: #C70F3F;
  background-image: url(../images/background/pageA.jpg);
}
```

But what I actually get is:

```
.pageA {
  background-color: $pageA;
  background-image: url(../images/background/pageA.jpg);
}
```

Is there a way to carry the variable into background-color?

Comment: Another downvote with no comment... why?

Comment: The Sass documentation is a single page long.  If you'd bothered to read it, you would have had your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an colors array:

```
$pageA : #C70F3F;
$pageB : #7f153b;
$pageC : #0c5451;
$pageD : #9f1023;

//############ page type array + colors in array

$pageTypes: pageA pageB pageC pageD;
$colors : $pageA, $pageB, $pageC, $pageD;


//############  loop
$i:0;
@each $pageType in $pageTypes {
  $i:$i+1;
  $thisColor:nth($colors,$i);
  .#{$pageType} {
    background-color:$thisColor;
    background-image:url(../images/background/#{$pageType}.jpg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not ideal as it relies on arrays being same order but it works!